# What contextual links would make full-text journal articles more useful?

Tags: publication-process

After searching PubMed or Google Scholar researchers often arrive at a publisher's full-text article page. Assuming that you have access to the full-text access, **what contextual links should be included within the article?** i,e links to Brain Atlas, links to Gene Databases

Comment: Thanks for asking. I've given this question an edit, but I'm still not sure whether it is a good fit for the site. It is fairly subjective and could potentially vary a lot across disciplines.

Comment: Also to clarify, are you talking only about links in the PDF/HTML of the full-text article or are you also talking about side bar links (e.g., options to export bibliographic information links to related articles, view statistics, etc.)

Comment: I don't think there's any definitive answer to this at all, it's not more than a poll (I meant to clarify that earlier but I got sidetracked).

Comment: I'm in agreement, this feels too subjective to me. user2366, we expect questions on this site to have a definitive *correct* answer, and I'm not sure this question has one...

Comment: I think this question might be off-topic for here, and a better fit at [academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective question and what is useful would depend on from which domain of cognitive science the article originated. In general, I prefer when the PDF looks like the journal article (i.e., no formatting to indicate links).

Here is a list of things that I find useful:

- Links from in text citations to the location of the full reference
- Links from references to the full-text resource
- Links between Table and figure references with the actual figure
- Table of contents tied to sections in the article
- URLs and emails that can be clicked on
- Tables with exportable data
- If the article includes supplementary material, links to that material that work and do not require password access.

A few extra things that might be nice perhaps in the HTML version:

- Ability to export both the article reference and the references in the  article in various bibliographic formats (e.g., bibtex, Endnote, etc.)
- Page view, download, and citation statistics
- RSS feed options for the journal